# SSH terminal locks after remote reboot

Tags: command-line, ssh, reboot, remote

Whenever I am remotely logged into another machine and I type:

> sudo reboot

The terminal locks up for a significant period of time. So far the only solution that I've come up with is this

> sudo reboot && exit && exit

The 2nd exit is because sometimes the first one doesn't work in the millisecond response.

I was wondering if there was a prettier way of doing things such that the terminal doesn't lock up and merely drops to the local machine.

Comment: have you tried `echo "alias reboot='reboot && exit && exit'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: that way it does it all for you

Comment: yeah, I've done that, but you're missing sudo

Comment: well, I left sudo out so that `sudo reboot` wouldn't translate to `sudo sudo reboot`

Comment: But did aliasing it work?

Comment: Yes, aliasing did work, as long as extra "&& exit"'s are included. Since the extra exit tack ons make this a somewhat cumbersome approach.

Comment: I would just stick the alias command in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or something and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read `man ssh`? It shows how you can use an "Escape Character" sequence:

```
ESCAPE CHARACTERS
     When a pseudo-terminal has been requested, ssh supports a number of
     functions through the use of an escape character.

     A single tilde character can be sent as ~~ or by following the tilde by a
     character other than those described below.  The escape character must
     always follow a newline to be interpreted as special.  The escape
     character can be changed in configuration files using the EscapeChar
     configuration directive or on the command line by the -e option.

     The supported escapes (assuming the default ‘~’) are:

     ~.      Disconnect.

     ~^Z     Background ssh.

     ~#      List forwarded connections.

     ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded connection /
             X11 sessions to terminate.

     ~?      Display a list of escape characters.
```

Comment: I had actually encountered this same solution elsewhere on stack exchange, but it appears to not work in some situations. I'll keep trying it and report back after some time.